# Mathematica outputs its input; Eigensystem

Tags: matrix, output, eigenvalues

I am simply trying to find the eigenvalues of a symbolic matrix using Matematica, but it does not give me an answer; it just outputs its input.

(u is a parameter)

```
y0 = (u - 1)^(1/2);
jacob = {{-1, 0}, {y0, -2 y0^2}} // MatrixForm // Eigensystem
```

Output:

[image]

Why is that so? and How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
y0 = (u - 1)^(1/2);
jacob = {{-1, 0}, {y0, -2 y0^2}} // Eigensystem
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`MatrixForm` got in the way of your computation.

---

To be able to use `MatrixForm` and not have it stop your computation, one option is

```
y0 = (u - 1)^(1/2);
(jacob = {{-1, 0}, {y0, -2 y0^2}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Eigensystem[jacob]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Added verification by hand per comment. Mathematica result is correct.

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
\sqrt{u-1} & -2\left(  u-1\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence
$$
\left\vert A-\lambda I\right\vert =
\begin{vmatrix}
-1-\lambda & 0\\
\sqrt{u-1} & -2\left(  u-1\right)  -\lambda
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Therefore $\left\vert A-\lambda I\right\vert =0$ gives
\begin{align*}
\left(  -1-\lambda\right)  \left(  -2\left(  u-1\right)  -\lambda\right)    &
=0\\
2u-\lambda+2u\lambda+\lambda^{2}-2  & =0\\
\lambda^{2}+\lambda\left(  2u-1\right)  -2+2u  & =0
\end{align*}
Using the quadratic formula $\lambda=\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt
{b^{2}-4ac}$ the roots are
\begin{align*}
\lambda & =\frac{-\left(  2u-1\right)  }{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left(
2u-1\right)  ^{2}-4\left(  -2+2u\right)  }\\
& =\frac{-2u+1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left(  2u-3\right)  ^{2}}\\
& =\frac{-2u+1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\left(  2u-3\right)
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{1}  & =\frac{-2u+1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(  2u-3\right)  \\
& =\frac{-2u}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+u-\frac{3}{2}\\
& =-u+\frac{1}{2}+u-\frac{3}{2}\\
& =-1
\end{align*}
And
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{2}  & =\frac{-2u+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(  2u-3\right)  \\
& =\frac{-2u}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-u+\frac{3}{2}\\
& =-u+\frac{1}{2}-u+\frac{3}{2}\\
& =-2u+2\\
& =-2\left(  u-1\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: it worked; why was `MatrixForm` causing problem?

Comment: By the way, a side question; which ones are eigenvectors and which ones are eigenvalues?

Comment: @onurcanbektas the first list is the eigenvalues. Second is the eigenvectors. They also go in that order with each others.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: By the way, sorry for further questions, but the result is wrong; $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of this matrix

Comment: `−1  is not an eigenvalue` I did not check by hand calculation. I assumed Mathematica is correct. `Eigenvalues[jacob]` also gives `{-1, -2 (-1 + u)}`. If you give me a minute or 2, will do it by hand and see. It is possible you discovered a bug otherwise. But need to check.

Comment: Thanks for further replies; apparently, while I was calculating the eigenvalue equation, I finding $y0 * 0 = y0$; what a mistake :) The result it correct; I also checked it with MATLAB in case I have further algebra mistakes

Comment: @onurcanbektas I just checked also by hand. Mathematica result is correct :)

Comment: thanks a lot, again :)